# Isabelle: changing an element inside a list

Tags: isabelle

In **VDM**, we can do something like the following

```
someSequence(index) := someSequence(index) union {x}
```

where someSequence is a sequence of sets.

In **Isabelle**, how can I access an element inside a list and modify it like the above example? Is there a way to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You talk about a sequenced set, but you ask about a list. Here's the list function:

```
value "(list_update [1,2,3,4,5::nat] 2 0) = [1,2,0,4,5]"
```

There is *main.pdf*, which gives a quick overview of functions and syntax for common types. On page 9 is the overview of lists:

https://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2015/dist/Isabelle2015/doc/main.pdf#page=9

I looked at the function signatures until I saw something that looked like it took and returned the right kind of arguments.

Their is a PDF for the Isabelle/HOL logic. Chapter 66 is where they define lists for Isabelle2015. Page numbers and chapters can change for a new release.

On page 1033, there is a list of checks they do that serve as examples of some common list functions:

https://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2015/dist/library/HOL/HOL/document.pdf#page=1033

They don't try to make the list function library exhaustive. You can use what they've done, for examples of how to define your own.